# Refer to enclosing class' this from anonymous inner class

Tags: java

Supposing you got the following code:

```
public abstract class DecisionFunctionJ {
    public abstract double evaluate();

    public DecisionFunctionJ add(final DecisionFunctionJ another) {
        return new DecisionFunctionJ() {
            @Override
            public double evaluate() {
                return this.evaluate() + another.evaluate();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This code does not work as intented because it leads into an endlessloop / `StackOverflowException`. The reason for this is clear: the `this.evaluate()` references the `evaluate` method of the inner anonymous class and not the `evaluate` method of the outer abstract class.

How can I execute the outer `evaluate` method? Using `DecisionFunctionJ.this.evaluate()` does not help because both classes are of type `DecitionFunctionJ`.

What are the other possibilities?

Comment: Have you tried using `DecisionFunctionJ.this`? I don't see how it won't work.

Comment: It's not really true that both classes are of type `DecisionFunctionJ`; the inner one has an unnamed type.  Yes, it's a subclass of `DecisionFunctionJ`, and `this instanceof DecisionFunctionJ` will be `true`.  **But for this purpose**, i.e. using it as a prefix of `.this`, that fact doesn't matter.  I agree with Rohit--I don't see how it won't work either.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thanks, I know how SO works, if you allow, I'd like to test it out before. :-/

Comment: Ok, that whole question was a little bit stupid, I converted a scala example, and it seems like scala depends different from Java here. I did not test well engouth, sorry for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `DecisionFunctionJ.this` reference to reference the enclosing class:

```
public abstract class DecisionFunctionJ {
    public abstract double evaluate();

    public DecisionFunctionJ add(final DecisionFunctionJ another) {
        return new DecisionFunctionJ() {
            @Override
            public double evaluate() {
                return DecisionFunctionJ.this.evaluate() + another.evaluate();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second private method to avoid the naming collision:

```
public abstract class DecisionFunctionJ {
    public abstract double evaluate();

    public DecisionFunctionJ add(final DecisionFunctionJ another) {
        return new DecisionFunctionJ() {
            @Override
            public double evaluate() {
                return outerEvaluate() + another.evaluate();
            }
        };
    }

    private double outerEvaluate(){
        return evaluate();
    }
}
```